# Show only columns from an string array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Table in my Entities with 370 columns ! Furthermore i have a string Array which is not known before runtime (comes from a website).

e.g.:

```
string [] columns = {"column1", "column2", "column3"}
```

How can i fire a linq to my entities which gives me only the result with the giving columns?

I searched for hours, but don`t suceed till now - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you can do with Linq-to-Entities. You need to be able to declare the columns in your code.

A better approach would be to create the query in Sql using the column names in your array, and use something like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to map the results to your objects.

Comment: This is not true. You can use reflection

Comment: and how can i use reflection - do you have an example ?

Comment: Even if it would work with reflection, this is a typical usecase that is *not* suited for LINQ to Entities. LINQ to Entities is ideal when you have your C# classes (Entities) and you want to make queries based on those. Here, old school `DataReader`s are far better suited it sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate an ExpandoObject in your Delegate and use Reflection to get the columns specified in the incoming array.

The following:

```
List<IDictionary<String, Object>> List = Context.Row_Type.Select(delegate(Row_Type Row) {

      IDictionary<String, Object> Out = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<String, Object>;

      PropertyInfo[] PIs = Row.GetType().GetProperties();

      foreach(PropertyInfo PI in PIs) {
        if(PI.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0) {
          Out.Add(PI.Name, PI.GetValue(Row));
        }
      }

      return Out;

    }).ToList();
```

Will return a List < IDictionary< String, Object>> with all the properties, to return the desired columns just discriminate by PI.Name:

```
    if(PI.Name == "Desired column"){ // Or Array index

       // Add to Out:
       Out.Add( PI.Name, PI.GetValue(Row) )

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing  you don't really want to return a class with unknown column names. Would a dictionary of column names and values work for you?  Your query would still have to retrieve all of the columns, but you can only return the ones you care about.

```
string [] columns = {"column1", "column2", "column3"}

var entity = GetEntity();
var dictionary = columns.ToDictionary(c => c, c => entity.GetType().GetProperty(c).GetValue(entity));
```

Or, if you have a collection...

```
var entities = GetEntities();
var results = entities
    .Select(e => columns.ToDictionary(c => c, c => e.GetType().GetProperty(c).GetValue(e)));
```

Comment: Wow - really cool, that solved my problems, that`s exactly what i need ! Thx a lot *thumbsUp*